# SFTP server not working

Tags: users, openssh, sftp

I'm kinda inexperienced at Linux, so I will just leave here all commands I used, to set up SFTP server on Ubuntu 18.04 Server.

My goal is to create an SFTP server, with the following criteria:

- All SFTP users are in "sftp_users" group.
- All users **DO NOT** have their own folder.
- All users have access **ONLY** to 1 common folder (/data/sftp).
- Anyone of SFTP users can read, write, execute (aka upload, download, delete, etc.) any file in this common folder.

Commands I used to set up a server

```
apt update
apt install openssh-server
mkdir -p /data/sftp
chmod 701 /data
groupadd sftp_users
useradd -g sftp_users -d /data/sftp -s /sbin/nologin sftptest
passwd sftptest
chown -R root:sftp_users /data/sftp
chown -R sftptest:sftp_users /data/sftp
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Added this lines at the end of file

```
Match Group sftp_users
ChrootDirectory /data/sftp
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

And did

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

When I`m trying to connect to the server by SFTP with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net), it gives me the error

```
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "sftptest".

Authentication failed.
```

---

Full log:

```
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.266 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.266 WinSCP Version 5.15.3 (Build 9730) (OS 10.0.17134 - Windows 10 Enterprise)
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.267 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.267 Log level: Normal
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.267 Local account: %PCNAME%
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.267 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.267 Process ID: 5780
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.267 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Time zone: Current: GMT+3, Standard: GMT+2 (FLE Standard Time), DST: GMT+3 (FLE Daylight Time), DST Start: 31.03.2019, DST End: 27.10.2019
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Login time: 10 August 2019 y. 23:49:45
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Session name: sftptest@%INTERNALIP% (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Host name: %INTERNALIP% (Port: 22)
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 User name: sftptest (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Tunnel: No
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Transfer Protocol: SFTP (SCP)
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Disable Nagle: No
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Proxy: None
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Send buffer: 262144
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Bypass authentication: No
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: Yes
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.275 GSSAPI: Forwarding: No; Libs: gssapi32,sspi,custom; Custom: 
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 Ciphers: aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 KEX: ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 Simple channel: Yes
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 Shell: default
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 EOL: LF, UTF: Auto
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No; Exit code 1 is error: No
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 SFTP Bugs: Auto,Auto
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 SFTP Server: default
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 DST mode: Unix
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.276 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.317 Looking up host "%INTERNALIP%" for SSH connection
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.317 Connecting to %INTERNALIP% port 22
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.349 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.15.3
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.380 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.380 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.381 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.784 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.785 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.785 ssh-ed25519 256 %FINGERPRINT% %KEY%
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816 Asking user:
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816 **Continue connecting to an unknown server and add its host key to a cache?**
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816 
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816 The server's host key was not found in the cache. You have no guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is.
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816 
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816 The server's Ed25519 key details are:
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816 
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816     Algorithm:    ssh-ed25519 256
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816     SHA-256:  %KEY%
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816     MD5:  %FINGERPRINT%
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816 
. 2019-08-10 23:49:45.816 If you trust this host, press Yes. To connect without adding host key to the cache, press No. To abandon the connection press Cancel. ()
. 2019-08-10 23:49:47.215 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2019-08-10 23:49:47.215 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2019-08-10 23:49:47.215 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2019-08-10 23:49:47.215 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
! 2019-08-10 23:49:47.259 Using username "sftptest".
. 2019-08-10 23:49:47.291 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,password
. 2019-08-10 23:49:47.291 Prompt (password, "SSH password", <no instructions>, "&Password: ")
. 2019-08-10 23:49:47.291 Using stored password.
. 2019-08-10 23:49:47.297 Sent password
. 2019-08-10 23:49:47.310 Access granted
. 2019-08-10 23:49:47.310 Opening session as main channel
. 2019-08-10 23:49:48.472 Network error: Software caused connection abort
* 2019-08-10 23:49:48.549 (EFatal) Network error: Software caused connection abort
* 2019-08-10 23:49:48.550 Authentication log (see session log for details):
* 2019-08-10 23:49:48.550 Using username "sftptest".
* 2019-08-10 23:49:48.550 
* 2019-08-10 23:49:48.550 Authentication failed.
```

Comment: IIRC the ChrootDirectory must be owned by root, and cannot itself be user-writeable. You may create a user- or group-writeable directory *within* the ChrootDirectory though. See for example [How can I chroot sftp-only SSH users into their homes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes)

Comment: `chmod 701 /data` I expect /data needs to be 755. But really, you should check syslog on the server to see if sshd is logging any helpful messages.

Comment: Okay, kinda working now. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, recommendations from comments helped me. The trick did next commands

```
chown root /data
chmod go-w /data
chown sftptest:sftp_users /data/sftp
chmod ug+rwX /data/sftp
chmod 755 /data
```

Also edited `sshd_config`. Changed

```
ChrootDirectory /data/sftp
```

with

```
ChrootDirectory /data
```

Comment: What does passwd have for user home folder after this?